# TypeError (Cannot visit Integer) when calling User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:email])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ruby 2.5 and rails 5.1.4, which should be compatible with each other. When im calling User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:email]), i got an error: TypeError (Cannot visit Integer)

The param email was passed correctly. Anyone know what is this about? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share what have written in your `User` model?

Comment: Yes, I think your ruby version is not compatible with rails version. Try to downgrade ruby version to 2.3, it'd be fine.

Comment: I followed https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04 to install ruby 2.5.0 and rails 5.1.4, so I believe they should be compatible?  The function 'find_for_database_authentication' is not defined by me